# How can I tell what mode my GCP Firestore Bucket is in?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie learning how to use Google Cloud Platform's Firestore NOSQL datastore.

I understand that the Firestore can be configured in ["Datastore Mode" or "Native Mode"](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore). But I don't know how to view/update this setting. How can I do that?

I created a new Firestore bucket through Terraform. It looks like this (bucket name redacted):

[image]

Where is the configuration setting showing if this Firestore bucket is in "Datastore Mode" or "Native Mode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore in Datastore mode or Native mode does not apply to Google Cloud Storage (which is what you are showing in your screenshot). Google Cloud Storage is just what it is, there are no multiple modes for it.

Instead, click on "Datastore" in the left menu on the Console and it will tell you in plain text in the top-right side what mode you are in. Datastore is what you are looking for, not Google Cloud Storage.